# Monitor current page webrtc with javascript

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am an old time user of Greasemonkey.
I appreciate customizing the websites i visit much.

Is it possible, in javascript, to grab current page's actives webrtc infos, to display them live?
(i could then inject a javascript function on the current page, and display the webrtc's infos)

I am a musician, i appreciate to see when there is a huge break in the stream coming in/out for example.

I have heard of `getStats()` but the only docs i could read sounded obscure...

SO is it just possible on an HTML page, to run a Javascript function that could read WebRTC infos, generated by the page the javascript is currently running on?

EDIT : I know `chrome://webrtc-internals/` for Chrome and `about:webrtc` for firefox. This is not my question at all. ;)

Answer (score 0):

in chrome there is the chrome://webrtc-internals tab which displays the getStats information (and a bit more) live. For Firefox you might try https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/new-tool-debugging-webrtc/

If you are looking to implement this yourself the code from
https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-externals/
might be a bit dated but should still be working.